# Rails: Allow subclasses to inherit relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a model that inherits from another model, the relationships are not inherited. It seems this is intentional, but for my purposes I want to inherit the relationships. What's the best way to inherit active record relationships?

e.g.

```
class User
  has_many :addresses
end

class OriginalUser < User
  default_scope where('created_at <= ', DateTime.now - 5.years)

  # how can I inherit the has_many :addresses relationship?
end
```

Comment: From the Rails console: `o = OriginalUser.new; o.addresses` should return `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`. Is there something in particular that isn't working?

Comment: After your comment @TK-421 I rechecked and it actually is not a problem. Not sure what I was thinking... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing you example with Rails 4.2.4 I found out that the relationships actually **is** inherited.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end

class OriginalUser < User
end
```

In rails console:

```
2.2.3 :001 > user = User.create({name: 'Martin'})
2.2.3 :002 > address = Address.create({city: 'Berlin'})
2.2.3 :003 > user.addresses << address
2.2.3 :004 > address.user
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Martin", created_at: "2015-10-09 18:15:17", updated_at: "2015-10-09 18:15:17"> 

2.2.3 :005 > original_user = OriginalUser.create({name: 'Steel'})
2.2.3 :006 > another_address = Address.create({city: 'Boulder'})
2.2.3 :007 > original_user.addresses << another_address
2.2.3 :008 > another_address.user
 => #<OriginalUser id: 2, name: "Steel", created_at: "2015-10-09 18:20:58", updated_at: "2015-10-09 18:20:58">
2.2.3 :009 > original_user.addresses
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Address id: 2, city: "Boulder", user_id: 2, created_at: "2015-10-09 18:22:14", updated_at: "2015-10-09 18:22:48">]>
```

Comment: So, I have NO idea what my problem was. But you're right, thank you.